# bash merge 2 files with common atributes

Tags: bash, file-io

I have two files and I would like to merge them. The files are like below:

**File 1:**

```
8870:0/28,13
8870:2/22,1
8870:2/25,3
887:3/29,1
886:1/40,4
886:1/41,2
886:1/43,4
```

**File 2:**

```
8870:0,16
8870:2,9
887:3,5
886:1,31
```

**Output:**

```
8870:0,16,13
8870:2,9,4
887:3,5,1
886:1,31,10
```

In other words, in the output I want the `F2` adding a column with the sum `w` of same `x:y (x:y/z,w)`.

Comment: Please use syntax highlighting/monospace font, otherwise it's fairly hard to read. What is `w`? Please elaborate more on what you are talking about.

Comment: 8870:0/28,13 -> x:y/z,w. I apologize for the misunderstanding

Comment: `8870:2/22,1` and `8870:2/25,3` and `8870:2,9` shouldn't give `8870:2,1,3,9` and not `8870:2,9,4`? BTW what have you done till now?

Comment: nope. file 1: x:y/z,w file 2: x:y,a and output file : x:y,a,b where b should be the same of w of the same x:y/z. I am wondering how can I manage this task in any platform. Now I have these files in unix, but this isn't my problem.

Comment: __Looking again__: `file1` line 2 and 3, `file2` line 2. Your x:y are always `8870:2`.  Your `w` are  `1` and `3`. Your a from file2 is `9`.  In your output file you provide those numbers `8870:2,9,4`. So you want even the sum of only the data from `file1`... Now I understand... BTW what have you tried till now?

Comment: Now you are right. Until now, I haven't tried anything yet. I wonder how can I manage this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I wonder how can I manage this task."* Do not wonder, be curious and read as you can about `sed` and `awk`. Take what it follow as an hint.

- First *convert* the format of file1 to the format of file2 discarding what is not needed.

  ```
  sed 's/\/.*\,/\,/' file1.txt   # here you erase what in between `/` and `,`
  ```

  then process it with `awk` and associative arrays

  ```
  sed 's/\/.*\,/\,/' file1.txt  \
  | awk -F ',' '{A[$1]=A[$1]+$2}END{for (b in A) print b","A[b]}' > file1b.txt
  ```

  `|` pipe redirection
  `\` it allows to continue in the next line (no other characters after)
  `> file1b.txt`, if you want you can redirect all to a new file.
- Now you can use again associative array of `awk` with the 2 files `file2.txt` and `file1b.txt` (you want to add to the file2.txt so you have to write it for first)

  ```
  awk -F ',' '{if (A[$1]=="" ) {A[$1]=A[$1]$2} \
  else {A[$1]=A[$1]","$2}}END{for (b in A) print b","A[b]}' \
     file2.txt file1b.txt | sort -nr
  ```

  The final `| sort -nr` sort the output in reverse order (`-r`) with numeric order (`-n`).

Note that you do not need to create the `file1b.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

( \
  cat file2.txt ; \
  sed 's/\/.*\,/\,/' file1.txt  |  \
  awk -F ',' '{A[$1]=A[$1]+$2}END{for (b in A) print b","A[b]}' ;
) | \
awk -F ',' '{if (A[$1]=="" ) {A[$1]=A[$1]$2} else {A[$1]=A[$1]","$2}} \
END{for (b in A) print b","A[b]}'| sort -nr
```